# Java - Android : Thread being called (run) twice

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, thread-safety

I would like some help regarding Java - Android MultiThreading

While learning to develop my app in a multi-threading way in order to take advantage of the ever-growing multi-core devices market share (most devices are quad core now, some even octo-core), I ran in a situation where my threads are either being calling twice or running twice.

I just don't why and how.

**[EDIT 3]**
Alright, I narrowed down the issue : I called the `AsyncTask` from the `onResume()` method. Although my app did not lost focus (which would mean a call to `onPause()` then back to `onResume()` upon return of focus in which case my threads would be run twice) during the tests, I solved the issue by moving away the call to `FetchFriendsList` to another place.
So far so good, but since in my tests the app did not loose focus or perhaps it did but I could not witness it (!), I think there is another reason behind so I'd say my problem is not entirely solved ... at least for the moment. It does work though. Perhaps I did solve the issue but I do not know how :(
**[end of EDIT 3]**

I am implementing last Facebook SDK and I am using it to fetch the end-user friends list, which seems to do the work.
Since I am running this operation in an AsyncTask, I am not using `request.executeAsync()`.
Instead I am using `request.executeAndWait()`. Facebook JavaDoc does state that this method must only be used if I am not in a the Main UI Thread which is my case otherwise I would get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Anyway, this is where the weird behavior is happening.

```
private final ArrayList<GraphUser> userFriendsList = new ArrayList<GraphUser>(); 
public final void fetchFriendsList() {
    if (this.session != null && this.session.isOpened()) {
        final Request requestUserFriendsList = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(
                this.session, new Request.GraphUserListCallback()                                         
                    public final void onCompleted(final List<GraphUser> users, final Response response) {
                        if (users != null && users.size() > 0) {
                            Log.v("Retrieved Friends List -> ", String.valueOf(users.size()));
                            userFriendsList.addAll(users);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        if (this.asyncFlag)
            requestUserFriendsList.executeAsync();
        else
            requestUserFriendsList.executeAndWait();
    }
}
```

In my case, `asyncFlag` is set to false because I need to do stuff synchronously in that specific order :

1. Fetch User Friends List (not on the Main (UI) Thread)
2. Save friends list on device (separate new thread)
3. Save friends list on a server (separate new thread)

Following this pattern, the line `userFriendsList.addAll(users);` is called **twice**.
In the logcat, the `Log.v`is showed twice as well, and finally looking with the debugger, the content of the user friends list is made of duplicates.

But that's not all ...  step 2 and 3 are indeed two separate threads which are both created and spawned within the same method : `public final void asyncSaveFacebookFriendsList()`.

And guess what, this method is even called **twice** !

**just why ?**

At the beginning I was calling the method for step 2 and 3 like this :

```
[...]
userFriendsList.addAll(users);
asyncSaveFacebookFriendsList(); // it was private before
[...]
```

This is where the issue started as both line were running twice.

So I thought, alright, I'll call it later like this :

```
[...]
fetchFriendsList();
asyncSaveFacebookFriendsList(); // it is now public
[...]
```

But the issue remains still.
If I don't call `public final void asyncSaveFacebookFriendsList()`, then nothing is run **twice**.

Why does this issue happen ? Is there something I did not get in Java Threads ?

I do not think this is somehow related to the Facebook SDK because following the same pattern (and doing it also at the same time), I have the same issues when fetching and storing the end-user Twitter friends list.

So I do believe I am doing something wrong. Does someone have any idea in what possible case a thread is called twice ?

**Note** : all threads are started this way : `thread.start()`. I am not using any `ThreadPool` nor the `ExecutorService`.

In case you need more background context :
Content of AsyncTask : (no need to wonder why Void and Long, I remove the irrelevant code related to it)

```
private final class FetchFriendsLists extends AsyncTask<Long, Integer, Void> {
        protected final Void doInBackground(final Long... params) {
            if (params[0] != Long.valueOf(-1)) {
                [...]
                twitterAPI.fetchUserFriendsList();
                publishProgress(1, -1);
            }
            if (params[1] == Long.valueOf(0)) {
                [...]
                facebookAPI.fetchFriendsList();
                publishProgress(-1, 0);
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected final void onProgressUpdate(Integer... flags) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(flags);
            if (flags[0] != -1)
                twitterAPI.asyncSaveFacebookFriendsList();
            if (flags[1] == 0)
                facebookAPI.asyncSaveFacebookFriendsList();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I start step 2 and 3 in `onPublishProgress()` which runs on the Main UI Thread. Brefore it was in the `doInBackground()` method : the issue happens in both cases!

[EDIT]
After further test, it would seem any kind of code is in fact running twice.
I created a simple method called test in which in print a counter. The counter incremente twice as well !

Comment: There is nothing here to explain your problem. The critical issues are how you start and stop threads, how you synchronise them, and what shared memory they have. None of that is visible here.

Comment: @david.pfx I agree with you. But as described in my second edit, the problem might come from the Android Life Cycle. The `AsyncTask` being called from the `onCreate()` method, it is subject to be called even though the user doesn't interact (lockscreen, app looses focus etc.), therefore my Task might be called twice. I fixed that and for now it works just fine. However, I am not completely convinced, so I'll make some further tests and provide a full answer later.

Answer (score 1):

Why you use onProgressUpdate?¿?

> onProgressUpdate(Progress...), [...]. This method is used to **display any form of progress** in the
>   user interface while the background computation is still executing.
>   For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
>   a text field.

This is used not at the finish of the petition, but when progress increased.

Read this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You need to use:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with it, however, I tried to understand where, when and how my code is being run twice so I used `onProgressUpdate()` that runs on the main UI thread to see what happens. It is defenitely not a proper usage, but nevertheless, it was for debugging only. I assure you I removed the code afterwards.

Comment: @Mackovich If the class FetchFriendsList is not your real class, please, provide the original class, provide code as it's then we can read and look for bugs.

Comment: As explained in my OP's last edit, I narrowed down the problem to handling the Android Activity Life Cycle. So far so good : my threads are note run twice : I moved away the call of `FetechFriendsList`from the `onResume()` method. It was silly of me, but I am still on a learning-developpement pattern. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your welcome! and welcome to android ;). You can accept the answer if helps you.

Comment: Thank you @Sulfkain ! That is kind of you, although ... quite a bit strange to say this so long after my comment ^^ Now I am on Xamarin ! :)

Comment: hehehe yes, strange. I didn't see until now your response, sorry

Comment: please do not apologize ! You're the first to welcome me into android fold :D